# Mapped Data Not Displayed After React Query Refetch

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a react page that fetches data from a query using React Query, maps some more data with the results, and displays the data in a table.

The data is refetched if the user changes a value from a drop down that contains a context value.

The problem is after the refetch, the mapped data is not being shown, only the results of the refetch.

```
const contextValue = useContext(IdContext);
const id = useRef(contextValue.id);

const { data,
        error,
        isError,
        isLoading,
        refetch,
        isFetching,
        isFetched } = useGetData(axios, contextValue.id);

useEffect(() => {
        data.map(d => {
            d.value = getValue(d.id).toString();
            return true;
        });
    }, [data, isFetched]);

useEffect(() => {
        if (id.current !== contextValue.id) {
            refetch();
        }

        return () => { id.current = contextValue.id }
    }, [contextValue]);

return (
        <>
            {!isLoading && isFetched && (....
```

So the table shows the correct data that has been mapped on intial load, but if a different id is selected from the drop down, the table shows the data from the refresh but not the values that should be mapped.

Comment: You should not update *data* directly. Also, can you show the declaration for useGetData. Is useGetData used only for your specific use-case? If yes that you can have a internal state in your custom hook to store the modified data and just expose that data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic example of a place where [you don't need useEffect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state). Instead you should be using a selector to transform the data the query is providing into the data the component expects.

e.g.

```js
// You don't need to keep an extra copy of the id in a ref, just get it directly.

const { id } = useContext(IdContext);

const { data,
        error,
        isError,
        isLoading,
        refetch,
        isFetching,
        isFetched } = useGetData(id, { select: decorateValues });

return (
        <>
            {!isLoading && (....
```

Where your `useGetData` is defined something like:

```js
const useGetData = (id, options = {}) => {
   //...
   return useQuery({queryKey, queryFn, ...options});
}
```

and `decorateValues` is defined as a [selector](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/reference/useQuery) for the query.
e.g.

```js
const decorateValues = data => 
  data.map(item => ({ ...item, value: getValue(item.id).toString() }))
```

This selector will transform the value you get in the `data` key of your query bundle, so you can just read it directly in your component.